# How Can i Control that Mysql Server exists in Services with C# commands?

Tags: c#, mysql, service

How Can i Control that Mysql Server exists in services if its "displayname" and "servicename" is not "MySql" With C# Commands?

I can control with "ServiceController.GetServices();" if "displayname" and "servicename" is "MySql",but when i change that names,i cant control if that mysql server exists in Services or installed in my computer?

How can i control mysql server in my computer by using C# commands?

**MyCode**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {         
        bool sonuc = serviceExists("mysql");
        if(sonuc==true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MySQL Exists.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MySQL doesnt exist.");
        }

    }

    public bool serviceExists(string ServiceName)
    {
        return ServiceController.GetServices().Any(serviceController => serviceController.ServiceName.Equals(ServiceName));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually quite easy,

First have a look at the existing processes by simply asking windows using Process in namespace System.Diagnostics code like this.

```
Process[] ProcessList = Process.GetProcesses()
 var started= ProcessList.Any(a => a.ProcessName.Equals("mysql", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

The problem though is, what name MySql using, is it the default or is it another name, then the question is how many of them are there.

Perhaps, one option for you is to have a look at the port and have a look what applications are listening on a given network port as this is more reliable as the port might give you more information on the installation you're facing.

So, what I do is I get all IP handles of all network cards and have a look of who is talking with who. 
My code

```
var ip = new TCP().GetAllTcpConnections();
```

this returns a class with the following  signature:

```
public class TcpProcessRecord
{
    [DisplayName("Local Address")]
     public IPAddress LocalAddress { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Local Port")]
     public ushort LocalPort { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Remote Address")]
     public IPAddress RemoteAddress { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Remote Port")]
     public ushort RemotePort { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("State")]
     public MibTcpState State { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Process ID")]
     public int ProcessId { get; set; }
     [DisplayName("Process Name")]
     public string ProcessName { get; set; }
}
```

When you match the process ID's returned from Process.GetProcesses()
you know what application has a network connection and on what port it's trying to do it.

**This is also handy to see if your service is not available as your firewall is blocking a given port..**

The magic is in some code i found, had to update it a little as some methods of the original code became deprecated with .net 4.7.X

I'm not sure where I found the original code however here is my version

```
public class TCP
    {
        #region TCP
        private const int AF_INET = 2;

        // The GetExtendedTcpTable function retrieves a table that contains a list of 
        // TCP endpoints available to the application. Decorating the function with 
        // DllImport attribute indicates that the attributed method is exposed by an 
        // unmanaged dynamic-link library 'iphlpapi.dll' as a static entry point. 
        [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint GetExtendedTcpTable(IntPtr pTcpTable, ref int pdwSize, bool bOrder, int ulAf, TcpTableClass tableClass, uint reserved = 0);

        /// <summary> 
        /// This function reads and parses the active TCP socket connections available 
        /// and stores them in a list. 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <returns> 
        /// It returns the current set of TCP socket connections which are active. 
        /// </returns> 
        /// <exception cref="OutOfMemoryException"> 
        /// This exception may be thrown by the function Marshal.AllocHGlobal when there 
        /// is insufficient memory to satisfy the request. 
        /// </exception> 
        public List<TcpProcessRecord> GetAllTcpConnections()
        {
            int bufferSize = 0;
            List<TcpProcessRecord> tcpTableRecords = new List<TcpProcessRecord>();

            // Getting the size of TCP table, that is returned in 'bufferSize' variable. 
            uint result = GetExtendedTcpTable(IntPtr.Zero, ref bufferSize, true, AF_INET, TcpTableClass.TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL);

            // Allocating memory from the unmanaged memory of the process by using the 
            // specified number of bytes in 'bufferSize' variable. 
            IntPtr tcpTableRecordsPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);

            try
            {
                // The size of the table returned in 'bufferSize' variable in previous 
                // call must be used in this subsequent call to 'GetExtendedTcpTable' 
                // function in order to successfully retrieve the table. 
                result = GetExtendedTcpTable(tcpTableRecordsPtr, ref bufferSize, true, AF_INET, TcpTableClass.TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL);

                // Non-zero value represent the function 'GetExtendedTcpTable' failed, 
                // hence empty list is returned to the caller function. 
                if (result != 0)
                    return new List<TcpProcessRecord>();

                // Marshals data from an unmanaged block of memory to a newly allocated 
                // managed object 'tcpRecordsTable' of type 'MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID' 
                // to get number of entries of the specified TCP table structure. 
                MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID tcpRecordsTable = (MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tcpTableRecordsPtr, typeof(MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID));
                IntPtr tableRowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)tcpTableRecordsPtr + Marshal.SizeOf(tcpRecordsTable.dwNumEntries));

                // Reading and parsing the TCP records one by one from the table and 
                // storing them in a list of 'TcpProcessRecord' structure type objects. 
                for (int row = 0; row < tcpRecordsTable.dwNumEntries; row++)
                {
                    MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID tcpRow = (MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tableRowPtr, typeof(MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID));
                    tcpTableRecords.Add(new TcpProcessRecord(
                                          new IPAddress(tcpRow.localAddr),
                                          new IPAddress(tcpRow.remoteAddr),
                                          BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[2] {
                                              tcpRow.localPort[1],
                                              tcpRow.localPort[0] }, 0),
                                          BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[2] {
                                              tcpRow.remotePort[1],
                                              tcpRow.remotePort[0] }, 0),
                                          tcpRow.owningPid, tcpRow.state));
                    tableRowPtr = (IntPtr)((long)tableRowPtr + Marshal.SizeOf(tcpRow));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tcpTableRecordsPtr);
            }
            return tcpTableRecords != null ? tcpTableRecords.Distinct().ToList<TcpProcessRecord>() : new List<TcpProcessRecord>();
        }


        enum TcpTableClass
        {
            TCP_TABLE_BASIC_LISTENER,
            TCP_TABLE_BASIC_CONNECTIONS,
            TCP_TABLE_BASIC_ALL,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_LISTENER,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_LISTENER,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_CONNECTIONS,
            TCP_TABLE_OWNER_MODULE_ALL
        }

        // Enum for different possible states of TCP connection 

        public enum MibTcpState
        {
            CLOSED = 1,
            LISTENING = 2,
            SYN_SENT = 3,
            SYN_RCVD = 4,
            ESTABLISHED = 5,
            FIN_WAIT1 = 6,
            FIN_WAIT2 = 7,
            CLOSE_WAIT = 8,
            CLOSING = 9,
            LAST_ACK = 10,
            TIME_WAIT = 11,
            DELETE_TCB = 12,
            NONE = 0
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID
        {
            public MibTcpState state;
            public uint localAddr;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public byte[] localPort;
            public uint remoteAddr;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public byte[] remotePort;
            public int owningPid;
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// The structure contains a table of process IDs (PIDs) and the IPv4 TCP links that  
        /// are context bound to these PIDs. 
        /// </summary> 
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID
        {
            public uint dwNumEntries;
            // [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 1)]
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStruct, SizeConst = 1)]
            public MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[] table;
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// This class provides access an IPv4 TCP connection addresses and ports and its 
        /// associated Process IDs and names. 
        /// </summary> 
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class TcpProcessRecord
        {
            [DisplayName("Local Address")]
            public IPAddress LocalAddress { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Local Port")]
            public ushort LocalPort { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Remote Address")]
            public IPAddress RemoteAddress { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Remote Port")]
            public ushort RemotePort { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("State")]
            public MibTcpState State { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Process ID")]
            public int ProcessId { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Process Name")]
            public string ProcessName { get; set; }

            public TcpProcessRecord(IPAddress localIp, IPAddress remoteIp, ushort localPort,
                ushort remotePort, int pId, MibTcpState state)
            {
                LocalAddress = localIp;
                RemoteAddress = remoteIp;
                LocalPort = localPort;
                RemotePort = remotePort;
                State = state;
                ProcessId = pId;
                // Getting the process name associated with a process id. 
                if (Process.GetProcesses().Any(process => process.Id == pId))
                {
                    ProcessName = Process.GetProcessById(ProcessId).ProcessName;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary> 
        /// The structure contains an entry from the User Datagram Protocol (UDP) listener 
        /// table for IPv4 on the local computer. The entry also includes the process ID 
        /// (PID) that issued the call to the bind function for the UDP endpoint. 
        /// </summary> 
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MIB_UDPROW_OWNER_PID
        {
            public uint localAddr;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
            public byte[] localPort;
            public int owningPid;
        }


        #endregion

    }
```

Happy Coding